# Lighttpd running on Android Service

Tags: java, android, web-services, lighttpd

I'm working on an App that runs a webservice hosted an Android device. I'm using a basic webserver right now and have been asked to be able to support technologies such as FastCGI. I found Lighttpd which seems like it might satisfy, but I don't know where to begin with integrating it to Android. Does anyone have any suggestions of where to look to find an example of such a use. I'm open to any webserver as long as it supports FastCGI.

Comment: If you are planning on shipping this app, I hope you have a very large legal defense fund, as running open ports on a mobile device lacking a firewall seems like a fairly scary proposition.

Comment: @Mike How I have integrated Lighttpd in aosp ? Can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is blog post about successful build: http://hex.ro/wp/blog/php-and-lighttpd-for-android/

It might help you to begin.